# How to make a good height and weight table?

Tags: system-agnostic, statistics, game-design

I am wondering how I would make a good height and weight table that has balanced ranges across a range of around 6-8 feet. When I have tried making a table, it always ended up being too light for taller characters and too heavy for shorter characters. Is there a way to make height and weight scale well?

Comment: Welcome to the stack AshDrake, take the [tour] when you have a moment. If all you are looking for is realistic height to weight tables for different body compositions, then this question isn't on topic for the stack. I'm voting to close for "needs details" for now, it isn't clear to me that this is an RPG question and not just a question about humanoid morphology.

Comment: Where should I post this then?

Comment: We do maintain a list of RPG forums that cover a much broader range of topics, you may be able to find one better suited for your question: [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449)

Comment: Worldbuilding.stackexchange.com would be a reasonable candidate as well - this kind of question, with two or three times as many details, might be a good fit.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The specific range of 6-8 feet seems to imply that there is a specific race or species you are thinking of in a specific setting; this information would help guide possible answers.

Comment: I have moved this question to r/rpgdesign, as it would be more fitting there

Answer (score 4):

## Define sensible goals

What is a sensible Weight to Height? Some game designers (Looking at you, GURPS) choose some kind of variation of one of two systems to inspire their description of a race that is humanoid and follows roughly human proportions:

- [Body-Mass-Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index) \$Bmi=\frac M {h^2}\$ - the Mass in kilos divided by the height in meters **squared**
- [Corpulence-Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpulence_index) \$Ci=\frac M {h^3}\$ - the Mass in kilos is divided by the height in meters **cubed**

The two use different scaling:

**BMI** is a number typically read from a set of tables, that belong to different body heights. As a result,  different ethnic groups have different normal values: Underweight is often regarded of 18.5 and less, overweight 25+ and 30+ is obese. However, this does not account for the fact that the volume of a body scales with the third exponent, not 2nd, which is why these factors are shifted for different heights and populations: Singapore regards overweight starting at 23 while its average population is shorter than the US, which uses 25 as the overweight point. BMI does not calculate in that muscle is much heavier than fat, so that for example very tall but muscled people are regarded as overweight by the numbers alone.

For a human, the average **Ci** is regarded 12 for normal weight, as soon as they are no longer a baby, and has the benefit of not needing to be scaled for height as BMI does.

### Applying such values - inside the Humanoid Box!

Now, you want to make sensible values, right? And the species is about human-shaped and roughly similar proportioned? Then we can play with the values.

#### Heavier race of 165 cm average height

Ok, let's start by plugging human anatomy and scaling just the muscle (or fat) up compared to the baseline but keep the height. The result is, that the mass goes up, but the height stays the same. For BMI, the average would move from 20 to a higher number, possibly up to 30 for a very muscular race. For the CI, a 15 to 16 would get a much more muscled person. These could be either Schwarzenegger-barbarian muscled or very rounded over, quite chubby but not yet obese, beings.

#### Equally massive race of shorter height

For a different experiment, we keep the mass the same but shorten the height. The result is too, that the BMI and CI increase, similar to the heavier race. For a BMI of 30 with a 140 cm body, the result is close to 60 kilos. However, that's a CI of 21, so it looks quite more packed than at the larger body. Do note that *normal weight* with a BMI of 20 equates to a CI of 14 for 140 cm height, showing how *bad* BMI is for extreme bodies. such values could be either quite more muscular or just a more chubby result, reminiscent of Dwarves (CI ~17-22) or pudgy halflings (CI ~15)

#### Taller but lighter races

Now, let's go taller. Taller means generally lower values. A 200 cm race with BMI 20 weighs 80 kilos, and has a CI of 10 - which is *slender as a beanstalk*. If we go to BMI 18, we are at CI 9, which is rather *elfish* with its 72 kilos. BMI 16 would get us 64 kilos and CI 8. That is **super** thin, *feeling* almost skeletonized - or rather... *haute-couture model*, because skeletons have much less flesh.

#### The undead and malnourishment

Just for comparison: The typical body has about 15% skeletal mass. That means a **skeleton** of average height has a BMI of 3 and a CI of 1.8.

A dried-out mummy with its flesh remaining weighs on average about 20 kilos at an average height, for a BMI of roughly 7.5 and a CI of 4.5

This puts our **lowest** CI at 5.5 to get a somewhat *barely alive but hyper malnourished* looking being, reminiscent of survivors and victims of famine or hunger. Humans look like walking Skeletons already at 6.5 (see below), so 5.5 is pretty much going into "little grey alien" anatomy territory.

Just to give you a picture: [This possibly disturbing photo](https://collections.ushmm.org/search/catalog/pa1036057) is of a person weighing only 47 kilos where 90 kilos was their original and relatively healthy weight - putting him at a tall 1.9 meters, and their CI at 6.8. Another Holocaust survivor was [quoted as](https://www.ellygotz.com/press/2017/07/02/holocaust-survivor-plane-elly-gotz#:%7E:text=do%20it!%27-,%22,weight%20was%20just%2065%20pounds.) being only 32 kilograms (70 pounds), their father 5 pounds less (29.7 kilograms). Assuming the average height of 1.65 meters gets us a CI of 6.6 for the father.

### When BMI and CI fail - Outside the Human box!

BMI and CI do only work for people of roughly human proportions. Beings of vastly different densities (plant-people, rock-beings) or with a totally different setup (more than 4 limbs or extreme physique like the typical "grey alien) won't easily work out with similar values.

#### Different Material?

Non-standard Density can be roughly estimated by taking human density as 1 g/cm³, and thus just multiplying the estimated weight with the density of the other material average. Fir-people thus get a multiplier of about 0.5 to 0.75 (if they are construction-wood dry), and Granite-people get about 2.7.

#### Breaking the humanoid Mold

For extra limbs, you can get a multiplication factor for the estimated weight using an [amputee-adjustment formula](https://www.visualveggies.com/calculating-ideal-body-weight-for-amputees): an arm counts as 5% of the body weight, a leg as 16%. A balancing tail or hand might be the same 1%, while a meaty tail akin to a reptile might be up to another leg.

So we have an Angel and discarding the wings we get a weight of, let's say 100 kilos for their height using the humanoid approach. Now we estimate their wings have about somewhere between the weight of his arm and his leg, so 10% of the base body weight per wing. $$100\ \text{kg}\times(100\%+ 2\times 10\%)=100\ \text{kg}\times 1.2=120\ \text{kg}$$

#### Truely non-humanoid

Truly non-human physiology (Treants) is better estimated by designing a typical physiology from simple bodies, then multiplying the volume with their *average density*, which is basically 1 for all organic beings from flesh and bone or the material you chose them to be.

Thus, a 4-meter tall treeant with, about 1.5 meter at the base and 1 meter at the top, plus about a disk of of 1 meter height and 2 meters that is all the roots, limbs and smaller branches combined. As a result, he has a volume of roundabout 8 m³ and, if he's a white oak, weigh about 5.8 tons - if dry like construction wood. Round up for flowing sap to about 6 tons, and we got a baseline "Treant".

Answer (score -1):

It's tough to answer without knowing what your goals are. Here's one way to avoid the "tall characters are too light" problem:

Use the first roll to generate a height and standard weight. Then a second roll to vary from the standard weight.

E.g. first roll gives 6'0", 180lbs. Then add or subtract 1d10 pounds.

Or use a lookup table to give the adjustment roll more range.